# iOS automated test framework that allows image comparison

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests

There are a lot of iOS automated test frameworks out there, but I'm looking for one that allows comparison of images with previous images at that location. Specifically, the best method would be for me to be able to take an element that contains an image, such as a UIImageView, and test to see whether the image in it matches a previously taken image during that point of the testing process.

It's unclear to me which of the many frameworks I've looked at allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Zucchini](http://www.zucchiniframework.org)!

It allows you to take screenshots at different points in the app testing process, and compare them against previous versions. There is some help about such as [this video](https://vimeo.com/channels/390917/49277884) and [this tutorial](http://doronkatz.com/user-acceptance-testing-tutorial-on-zucchini-part-1-getting-started/).

For comparing specific parts of a UI, you can use the masks feature they support to only compare relevant parts of the UI.

You can also check out the [demo project](https://github.com/rajbeniwal/zucchini-demo).